# install cURL on a virtual machine (virtualbox)

Tags: php, curl, twitter, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I want to make stress tests on a virtual machine, I want to test the response time for a twitter request but when I try to access the page i'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'You need to install cURL, see: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html' in /var/www/assignment2/old_app/TwitterAPIExchange.php:37 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/assignment2/old_app/twt.php(33): TwitterAPIExchange->__construct(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/assignment2/old_app/TwitterAPIExchange.php on line 37
```

how do I install cURL on a virtual machine? 
this code is originally hosted in a hosting server therefore I never had to make any installations...

Comment: check this option set or not `extension=php_curl.dll` in php.ini file - you can use phpinfo() to check the configuration

Comment: could you be more specific? what do I need to run in the command line?

Comment: You need to find the php.ini file on your server open it and search for extension=php_curl.dll - if it is commented out you need to remove the comment and restart your web service.

Comment: not in command line, in your php file, please check with the curl set or not `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` . And if not set, then you can use `<?php ini_set('extension', 'php_curl.dll'); phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: I need to use it in my twitter php file ? if not than how do I find the "php.ini" file? It's a virtual machine that contain many data and installation that I did not created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a lot of help if you specify more details, like what operating system you are using for the Virtual Machine, what PHP versions are installed etc.

Anyway, you need to install curl on the machine if it is not already installed :

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html

After you install cURL (or verify it is installed) you need to install PHP cURL bindings :

You can either follow instructions on this page : http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

Or if your virtual machine is using a linux distribution use its package management system to install it, for example on ubuntu you need to type the following command in a terminal :

`$ sudo apt-get install php5-curl`